# Is it possible to add bardic inspiration to time stop?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, bard, time

Wondering this because it would be pretty cool if you could make time stop more than 1d4 + 1 and have a really long time stop.

**Bardic Inspiration**

> Once within the next 10 minutes, the creature can roll the die and add
>   the number rolled to one ability check, Attack roll, or saving throw
>   it makes. The creature can wait until after it rolls The D20 before
>   deciding to use the Bardic Inspiration die, but must decide before the
>   DM says whether the roll succeeds or fails. Once the Bardic
>   Inspiration die is rolled, it is lost. A creature can have only one
>   Bardic Inspiration die at a time.

Answer (score 17):

No.  The 1d4+1 roll to see how many turns *time stop* gives you is not an ability check, attack roll, or saving throw, and thus Bardic Inspiration cannot be applied to it.  You can tell the roll is none of those things because it is not called any of those things, and also because ability checks, attack rolls, and saving throws all use d20's, not d4's.